# Why does this C program just stops while running and shows no output?

Tags: c

Hellow guys, my friend made this program (I don't know what he is actually doing), but he asked me for help because it was not executing properly. I have studied the C++ till Objects and Overloading. I looked at the code and it seemed fine but when I tried to execute, it does not execute properly, after asking for the height, the DOS stops working and gets clsoed. I tried to figure out the problem, but I could not.

Below is the code of the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int height, i, j;
    char character;

    printf("plz enter height\n");
    scanf("%d",height);

    printf("plz type character\n");
    scanf("%c",character);

    for(i=0;i<=height;i++){
        for(j=0;j<=i;j++){
        printf("%c",character);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: you're not passing the address of a writable location to `scanf` so it won't be able to write to those variables.

Comment: I voted to close as it is not clear what you are actually asking. But just try change `scanf("%d",height);` to `scanf("%d",&height);` and `scanf("%c",character);` to `scanf("%c",&character);` offline

Comment: You should use `putchar` instead of `printf`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    int height, i, j;
    char *character;

    printf("plz enter height\n");
    scanf("%d",&height);

    printf("plz type character\n");
    scanf("%s",&character); //if you consider charactere as string it works

    for(i=0;i<=height;i++){
        for(j=0;j<=i;j++){
        printf("%c",character);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. And excuse me : you have to add the "&" when you read integers. the char *character is a dynamic allocation of a string.